# Django Subquery Average Employee Salary Per Company

Tags: django, subquery

I was looking for a better way using Subquery annotate and Avg but couldn't figure it out.  This is what i have at the moment and it works giving me the average number of employees per company but it's ugly.

```
companies = Company.objects.all()
for company in companies:
    salary = []
    for emp in company.comp_emp.all():
        salary.append(emp.salary)
    print(sum(salary) / len(salary))

>>> 99054.4
>>> 96403.75
>>> 498351.375
```

I tried the following but no go,

```
companies = Employee.objects.filter(company=OuterRef('pk'))
employee_count = Company.objects.annotate(avg_emp_salary=Avg(Subquery(companies.values('salary')[:])))

>>> 46907.0
>>> 147288.0
>>> 43158.0
```

The values I get back are incorrect but I also can't make sense of where they're coming from either.  This is just for my own learning purposes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you include your models.

Comment: By the way, you're not calculating employee count here. You're calculating average wage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using Subquery is a bit of an overkill here. You can use a simpler syntax for this.

```
companies = Company.objects.annotate(avg_emp_salary=Avg('employee__salary'))
```

Comment: Thanks!  I guess I'm trying to wrap my head around subquery and the documentation on Django's site isn't making too much sense to me.  I guess I'll keep playing around with it and see what I find. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries. And a good way to thank me is to flag the answer as accepted. :)